# How to deny default scope for ActiveRecord entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, named-scope

I've created few scopes for my ActiveRecord entity and I want to enforce user using one of it. Is there a way to, say, throw an exception, if no named scope is selected. 
I.e., I want to dissallow this:

```
Entity.all
```

but allow this:

```
Entity.user(current_user)
```

Thanks

Comment: You are the user, aren't you? Have some discipline :-)

Comment: Yes, I am, so I want to protect me from shooting my leg :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the :all scope

```
scope :all, #something like throwing an exception or calling other query
```

Comment: I doubt the current_user is a class method of Entity, but via something like sentient_user gem, that would be `scope :all, Entity.user(User.current)`

Comment: you're right, but the idea stills the same, override :all scope

Comment: `scope :all, lambda{Entity.user(User.current)}` to evaluate at call time, my first one was also wrong, (still via sentient_user). Yes the idea holds.